# Workflow error "unexpected Token"

Tags: powershell, azure

I have the workflow below and I ge the error whenever I try to put it inside a workflow.

If I take it out of a workflow it works, I was wondering if there's some incorrect syntax I'm missing or even if this is not allowed n a workflow.

Apologies but my knowledge on workflows is limited (as you can probably tell). I'm ultimately trying to get the VMs to boot up in parallel.

```
workflow Set-AzureRmTags-and-Start {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$VmRG
    )
    $Start = Get-Date
    Write-Output "Time is" $Start
    $VmRGs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$VmRG*" }
    foreach ($VmRG in $VmRGs) {
        $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $VmRG.ResourceGroupName
        ForEach ($vm in $vms) {
            $tags2 = $_.Tags
            $tags2 ['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$False"; 
        }
        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Tag $tags2 -Force -Verbose
    }

    $Middle = Get-Date
    Write-Output "Time Taken To Assign Tags" ($Middle - $Start).Minutes "Minutes"

    ForEach -Parallel ($vm in $vms) {
        Start-AzureRmVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Verbose -Confirm:$false
    }
    $End = Get-Date
    Write-Output "Time Taken To Start VMs" ($End - $Middle).Minutes "Minutes"
    Write-Output "Total Time Taken" ($End - $Start).Minutes "Minutes"
}
```

The error is around `['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$False"; }` Error "Unexpected Token in Expression or Statement".

Any ideas how I could correct this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$VmRGs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$VmRG*" }
foreach ($VmRG in $VmRGs) {
    $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $VmRG.ResourceGroupName
    ForEach ($vm in $vms) {
        $tags2 = $_.Tags
        $tags2 ['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop'] = "$False"; 
    }
    Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Tag $tags2 -Force -Verbose
}
```

The line `$tags2 = $_.Tags` does not makes sense. There is no `$_` at this point.

I don't have any experience in Azure tags, but [the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags) contains sample code that your code should more closely emulate. Setting tags in their samples always seems to use a HashTable construct, like `@{ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop=$false}`

This section seems relevant to what you're trying to accomplish:

> To add tags to a resource group that has existing tags, retrieve the
>   existing tags, add the new tag, and reapply the tags:
>
> ```
> $tags = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name examplegroup).Tags 
> $tags += @{Status="Approved"} 
> Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Tag $tags -Name examplegroup
> ```

Up until now, I've never looked into workflows. After a little testing and a bit of research, it seems the 'unexpected Token' error is due the code existing in a workflow:

```
function Test-ArraySubscriptFn {
    $tags2 = @{}
    $tags2['asdf'] = $false
}


workflow Test-ArraySubscriptWf {
    $tags2 = @{}
    $tags2['asdf'] = $false    # error: Only variable names may be used as the target of an assignment statement

    $tags2.Add('asdf',$false)  # error: Method invocation is not supported in a Windows Powershell Workflow...

    $tags2 += @{'asdf'=$false} # no error
}
```

This is consistent with google search [results](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/f8ff85bf-bcd4-4cd0-a670-b876e3d2da78/execute-task-on-many-vms-in-parallel-and-collect-output-in-a-single-array-variable?forum=azureautomation). I guess we both need to do a bit of research on how workflows [differ from 'regular' powershell scripts](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response :)  The script itself works outside a workflow, which (in my head) means the script is ok, Is what you have pointed out relating to workflows? :)

Comment: The problem with the automatic variable `$_` would be the same in both a normal function and a workflow. With respect to the `$tags2['Shut...'] = "$false"`, it seems yes: the error is because workflows have restrictions that normal functions don't. Rewrite your code to follow the documented examples and it should work in a workflow.